# Navigate to a different route programmatically

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

I have a usecase where I have a list of elements inside some component similar to vanilla html select. I want, when user clicks on any of the element inside list, route should change. Can I use some regex while defining route and change route by using some API method from react router, onValueChange event of select?

Example 
Root route: /
List Data: Cat, Dog, Elephant

When someone clicks on Cat I want him to get navigated to /Cat, similarly /Dog, /Elephant.

Comment: Or just use the `Link` component (from react-router) for each item on your list with a route defined. unless im misunderstanding the question

Comment: I don't want to use the Link component because I want to dispatch an action and change piece of an application state stored in redux (say selectedAnimal : Cat) before navigation to other Route.

Comment: ok, so call an action for redux to dispatch.. after the dispatch use `browserHistory` to update the url

Comment: browserHistory is available as props inside the component?

Comment: `import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'` and then to update the url you would call `browserHistory.push('/Cat')` for instance. This is what I would do, but thats with the limited info I have from your question :)

Comment: `onChange(value) {
    this.props.saveSelectedAnimal(value, () => {
      this.props.history.push("/");
    });
  }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153828/discussion-between-john-ruddell-and-lokesh-agrawal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after talking about it for a bit. figured out what you were wanting to do.

you need to define a new route in react-router that you can use for this history change.. something like this:

```
<Route exact path="/:name" component={SomeComponent} />
```

in your component you have access to this "name" via `this.props.params.name`

you can also call an action to update the store before updating this route

---

Note: if you stay with v2... You should make your actions return a promise, so that you can just chain the event in your component. aka:

```
onChange={this.handleChange}

handleChange = (value) => { // assuming you have the value here.. it may be e is the function param and you get the value as e.target.value
    this.props.saveSelectedAnimal(value).then( () => {
        this.props.history.push("/"); 
    })
}
```

Comment: `import { browserHistory } from 'react-router' and then to update the url you would call browserHistory.push('/Cat')` BrowserHistory is not available in routerv4

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal looks like browserHistory is in react router v3. Either you can use the router via props like you have or you can make a helper function to give you the same functionality browserHistory gives.